# TS2322: Type '"auto"' is not assignable to type 'Direction'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When I use `dir="auto"` in an html file in my Angular 10 project.

```
<span dir="auto">
```

When I run `ng build` with `strictTemplates` enabled (specially when `strictAttributeTypes` is enabled), I got an error `TS2322: Type '"auto"' is not assignable to type 'Direction'`

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions":{...},
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": true, //<--- this
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

In HTML5 spec "auto" is valid for `dir` attribute.

TypeScript version: 4.0.2

Comment: typescript v4.0.2, IDE atom  -- @AustinTFrench

Comment: Atom? The text editor? Using plugins for HTML / TS then?

Comment: it dosen't matter at all, the error occures when running `ng build`, apart from the IDE at all.

Comment: type checking by typecript

Comment: Does it work in `ng serve`?  Because it works fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqdh7m?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: actually `ng serve` executes `ng build` under the hood.

Comment: Yes, duh. But the question remains. It might be a flag in your build config. It might be something else on your machine as I can't reproduce it.

Comment: this is because the `strictTemplates` flag in my tsconfig.json

Comment: You may want to read [Angular's documentation on troubleshooting template type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#troubleshooting-template-errors).

Comment: Most likely you're using Angular Material which has `Dir` directive that takes `dir` as an `@Input()` with `type Direction = 'ltr' | 'rtl';`

Comment: yes, I'm using Angular material, and I want to set dir to "auto", because I cannot know the text direction in compile time. @yurzui

Comment: Create directive that allows 'auto' and it will work

Comment: A fix is on the way: https://github.com/angular/components/pull/23906